# PHP MySQL select from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select data from three tables.

In php this just means checking all IDs in `people`, and then looping through the rest of the tables for data. Is this possible with one SQL query?

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT name, age, message, notes 
FROM people
INNER JOIN messages ON people.id = messages.id
INNER JOIN notes ON people.id = notes.id
WHERE replied = 'y'
```

[This is what I'm attempting to accomplish.](http://www.docspal.com/viewer?id=asrouivd-9276956)

Comment: Please include your table structures - specifically, *how* each of these tables relate to each other.  It is extremely likely that your joining on `people.id` to both `messages.id` and `notes.id` is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, I am a DB beginner. I don't have any relations there, I'm learning.

Comment: If your tables don't have any relations between each other, then what you are asking to do is impossible.  You need to add some column to the messages table that relates to people (e.g.: PeopleId), and use that field in the `JOIN` (e.g.: `JOIN messages ON people.id = messages.peopleid`).  Same situation for the notes table.  You need to define a relationship in order to `JOIN` the tables.

Comment: How are you looping through it in php to pull data?  When you pull an ID from the People table, how is that ID used to pull data from the messages and notes tables?

Comment: Perhaps you should try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`? (Move `replied = 'y'` to the `ON` clause to get correct left join behavior.)

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Anything not working with the given query?

Answer (score 1):

Check your column names and table relation by **columnId** or **name** .
In this case you have **name** , but name is not conpatible with messages.id or note.id, so add column Id for table people o add column name for tables messages and notes

Example:

```
SELECT  _id_  , name, age, message, notes 
    FROM people
    INNER JOIN messages ON people.id = _messages.peopleId_
    INNER JOIN notes ON people.id = _notes.peopleId_
WHERE replied = 'y'
```

Bye ^.^

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with your data structure. First every table definitely should have there own ID column (primary key - learn a little about that).

Second thing is that with your data structure you will have a problem with that who send a message and who receive that message if you will have more than two users. You have column replied (y/n) in message table but from this table structure can't connect one message with message on which you (or someone) replied.
Also there is no need for the table notes (I don't get there function), that table in data structure like this doesn't have much sense, you can simply add one more column in table message called notes and that will do the job for you...

Here is one simple example how your data can look like:

Table: people

```
+---------+----------+------------+
|peopleID |  Name    |    Age     |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 123qwe  | Tom      |    23      |
+---------+----------+------------+ 
| 456rty  | Andy     |    35      |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

Table: message

```
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+
|messageID| peopleID | messages   |          note           | replied    |
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+
|   1     | 123qwe   | Hi         | I have problem with this|    0       |
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+
|   3     | 123qwe   | Hello      | oh no                   |    0       | 
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+   
|   4     | 456rty   | Hi         | yeah                    |    3       | 
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+ 
|   5     | 123qwe   | hi         | boring                  |    4       | 
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+ 
|   7     | 456rty   | pfff       | what's new              |    0       | 
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+   
|   9     | 123qwe   | Hi         | nothing, I'm bored      |    7       | 
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+ 
|   10    | 456rty   | pf         | me to                   |    9       | 
+---------+----------+------------+-------------------------+------------+
```

So here instead of just have y/n value in replied column you'll have in that column value of messageID on which is that column answer. Also if there is value 0 in that column that mean that is the first message in conversation.

your query can for selecting message which have been answered can look like this

```
-- SELECT MESSAGE WHICH HAVE BEEN ANSWERED
SELECT m.messageID, p.name, p.age, m.messages, m.note
FROM people p
INNER JOIN message m
ON p.peopleID = m.peopleID
WHERE m.messageID IN (SELECT replied
                      FROM message
                      GROUP BY replied);
                 
-- SELECT MESSAGE WHICH    NOT   HAVE BEEN ANSWERED
SELECT m.messageID, p.name, p.age, m.messages, m.note
FROM people p
INNER JOIN message m
ON p.peopleID = m.peopleID
WHERE m.messageID NOT IN (SELECT replied
                          FROM message
                          GROUP BY replied);
```

[HERE is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97c5c/4) so you can see how it work...

that work's like this if you want to see message on which you got answer than simply you check if there is that messageID in replied column, if there is messageID in replied column that means that message got answer, if not that means that message didn't get answer...

If you need that third table note for some reason than you can simply add it to the query with one more inner join like you did already in your query.